# 2 children on minecraft...separate computers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have more than one child.  Can I use one minecraft game with 2 children on two separate computers? How can I do this?

Comment: Will they be playing on a server?

Comment: You mean one account or two?

Comment: Are you asking if you can use the same download but on two computers, or the same minecraft account? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

If they are playing separately, you could use the same account for both of them, however they wouldn't be able to connect to a server at the same time. But it would be fine for singleplayer.